# Jquery submit doesn't submit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My form submits fine using plain old `Javascript` but when I try to use `Jquery` it doesn't

The form...

```
<form class="control_select" name="audit_delete_form" id="audit_delete_form"
       method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <select id="audit_id_select" name="audit_id_select">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
               <? while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['auditID'].'">'.$row['auditName'].'</option>';}?>
            </select>
          <input type="submit" name="audit_delete_submit" id="audit_delete_submit" value="" />
        </form>
```

The php..

```
  if(isset($_POST['audit_delete_submit'])){
    $audit_id = $_POST['audit_id_select'];
    $sql = "UPDATE audit SET auditComplete = 1, deleted = 1 WHERE auditID = '$audit_id'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   }
```

The jquery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#audit_delete_submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x=document.forms["audit_delete_form"]["audit_id_select"].value;
        if(x==null || x=="") {
        $.msgbox("Please select an audit", {
        type:"alert",
        buttons: [
        {type: "submit", value: "OK"}
        ]
      });
    }else{
        $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this audit?", {   
        type: "confirm",
         buttons : [
            {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
            {type: "submit", value: "No"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
          ]
      }, function(result){
          if(result == "Yes"){
              alert(result);
              $("form#audit_delete_form").submit()
          }
      }); 
    }
  });
});
```

All of the `Jquery` works except the actual submit including the `alert(result)` which shows the correct value

Comment: You have a submit button, but you're not actually providing any kind of submit action. You need to use a [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function in your jquery; it doesn't inherit the HTML form action.

Comment: BS i say, your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/AmD6e/ (removed code for msgbox as that's not important to the submit working) The code you have provided does not recreate the problem.

Comment: Don't use short PHP open tags btw. Best user the full ones.

Comment: @KevinB that doesn't work for me

Comment: @tatty27 What browser? I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.62 m

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? do you not get alert("submitted")

Comment: What about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/AmD6e/1/

Comment: @EmmyS, I'm fairly new to jquery, how would I implement .post in my script?

Comment: @KevinB, the form does everything except the php, it alerts the value of result etc

Comment: @tatty27 Then this isn't related to the javascript. You aren't changing the form in any way when you do what you're doing with javascript.

Comment: And that's where you need `.post()`. You can also use @SirTophamHatt's solution and actually call the `submit()` function, but your current code isn't doing that; it's just displaying a submit button, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Where is @SirTophamHatt's solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird trick, but if you add a `return false` to the end of your function, the submit should work. I've been there, fixed that :)

```
   }
   return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: He's using `e.preventDefault()`, has the same effect in this case.

Comment: @sudipta, that doesn't do it I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the $.msgbox lib, but quickly scanning the API doc, it looks like you should put the callback function as a 'success' parameter of the options object:

```
$.msgbox("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this audit?", {   
    type: "confirm"
    , buttons : [
        {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
        {type: "submit", value: "No"},
        {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
    ]
    , success: function(result) {
        if(result == "Yes"){
            alert(result);
            $("form#audit_delete_form").submit()
         }
    }
});
```